# Dedicated Server - Dual Hard Drives Problem

Tags: 14.04, server

I recently purchased a dedicated server with 2x 3TB hard drives. When I type df -h in the terminal, I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2       1008G  883M  956G   1% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  500K  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/md1        488M   39M  424M   9% /boot
/dev/md3        1.7T   68M  1.7T   1% /home
```

Making me think the second drive ins't mounted? Any idea how I can go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: I notice you are using a virtual raid system, which I know nothing about.  Why are you doing that?  Perhaps it has something to do with the problem, because otherwise I don't really see any difference from normal partitioning.

Comment: Not too sure thats how the server came :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your machine has been configured with a software RAID1, which means both disks are mirrors of each other. If one fails, you'll still have your data intact.

Most likely both disks have the same partitioning layout on them:

1. boot partition /dev/sdX1
2. root partition /dev/sdX2
3. home partition /dev/sdX3

Where X is either a (first) or b (second) SATA disk.

Then the raid1 arrays were created:

1. /dev/md1 out of /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1
2. /dev/md2 out of /dev/sda2 and /dev/sdb2
3. /dev/md3 out of /dev/sda3 and /dev/sdb3

And finally you see that

- /dev/md1 is mounted at /boot
- /dev/md2 is mounted at /
- /dev/md3 is mounted at /home

You can check the status of your RAID1 mirrors:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

You can see that you have about 3TB of available space in total, which further confirms that they've used RAID1 which gives you redundancy at the cost of only being able to use half the physical disks' capacity.

Also, to further verify that you do have 2 hard drives in your machine, run:

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /dev'
```

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for the help!

Looks like the hard-drives are running on Raid 1. I'll have a look in changing it over to Raid 0. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Make sure you don't forget that with raid0 if you lose one disk, the whole dataset is gone. Ensure you have proper and regular backups if downtime isn't an issue in your environment.

PS. could you mark my response as the answer if you're happy with it? Thanks!